# Dynamically add new elements in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I’ve programmed a function that rotates objects around a main object, like how planets rotate around the sun.

I'm trying to dynamically add new planets in my little solar system by a simple click of a button. They are all SVG elements. I'm having trouble working out how I can dynamically generate new elements that rotate around the sun with my `rotation(coorX, coorY, object)` function. They would all need to be dynamically named and dynamically positioned, this is too hard on me.

What should my code need to look like in order for me to achieve this? Thank you in advance for any help/tips.

Here's my code:

```js
var objectX = "black";
function addObject(){
  objectX = "blue";
}

function rotation(coorX, coorY, object) {
 object.side +=  (1.0 / object.speed); 
 var ang = object.side * 2.0 * Math.PI / 180.0; 
 var r = object.spin;
 
 return {
  x: Math.cos(ang) * r - Math.sin(ang) * r + coorX, 
  y: Math.sin(ang) * r + Math.cos(ang) * r + coorY 
 };
  }  
  
  function rotationball ( circle ) {
 var x, y, x_black, y_black, e, newpos;
 e = document.getElementById ( circle );
 x_black = parseFloat ( document.getElementById ( objectX ).getAttribute ( "cx" ) );
 y_black = parseFloat ( document.getElementById ( objectX ).getAttribute ( "cy" ) );
 newpos = rotation( x_black, y_black, ball[circle] );
  
 e.setAttribute ( "cx", newpos.x );
 e.setAttribute ( "cy", newpos.y );
 }   
    
  var ball = { 
  blue: {speed: 1.2,  spin: 100, side: 0.0} , 
  red: {speed: 1.2,  spin: 200, side: 0.0}
 };
  
  function animate () {
   rotationball("blue"); 
   rotationball("red");   
 }       

var animateInterval = setInterval(animate, 1000 / 60);
```

```css
.st0{fill:black;}
.st1{fill:blue;}
.st2{fill:red;}
```

```html
<div class="spinning"> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="solly" viewBox="0 0 1000 600"><g id="Sun2">
  <circle id="black" class="st0" cx="500" cy="300.8" r="10"/>
  <circle id="blue" class="st1" cx="375.4" cy="289.7" r="10"/> 
    <circle id="red" class="st2" cx="375.4" cy="289.7" r="10"/> 
  
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="addObject()">
button
</button>
```

PS: I was also going to program that each added planet would be positioned a bit farther from the central point (the sun) than the previously added planet.

Comment: The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Looks like zessx was kind enough to fix it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're very much on the right track with your `ball` object (though I'd call it `balls`). To dynamically create a `circle` element you do this:

```
var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
```

Then you set its attributes (`circle.setAttribute`) and append it to the `id="Sun2"` element.

Here's a `makeBall` function that does that on the basis of a specification object you pass in which has two subobjects: `element`, which defines the element, and `animation` which defines the animation:

```
function makeBall(spec) {
  // Create the element
  var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
  // Set its various attributes
  ["id", "cx", "cy", "r", "class"].forEach(function(attrName) {
    circle.setAttribute(attrName, spec.element[attrName]);
  });
  // Add it to the sun
  document.getElementById("Sun2").appendChild(circle);
  // Remember its animation settings in `ball`
  ball[spec.element.id] = spec.animation;
}
```

Then you use it like this:

```
makeBall({
  element: {id: "blue", class: "st1", cx: "375.4", cy: "289.7", r: "10"},
  animation: {speed: 1.2, spin: 100, side: 0.0}
});
```

The last piece is to replace animate with something that works dynamically with the properties inside `ball`:

```
function animate() {
  Object.keys(ball).forEach(function(id) {
    rotationball(id);
  });
}
```

Here's an example removing `blue` and `red` from the markup and adding them dynamically when we start. I've also gotten rid of `objectX` and make the rotation always be relative to `black`, and hooked up some fields to use when adding a new ball:

```js
var ball = {};

makeBall({
  element: {id: "blue", class: "st1", r: "10"},
  animation: {speed: 1.2, spin: 20, side: 0.0}
});
makeBall({
  element: {id: "red", class: "st2", r: "10"},
  animation: {speed: 1.2, spin: 40, side: 120.0}
});
makeBall({
  element: {id: "yellow", class: "st3", r: "10"},
  animation: {speed: 1.2, spin: 60, side: 240.0}
});

function makeBall(spec) {
  // Create the element
  var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
  // Set its various attributes
  ["id", "cx", "cy", "r", "class"].forEach(function(attrName) {
    if (spec.element[attrName]) {
      circle.setAttribute(attrName, spec.element[attrName]);
    }
  });
  // Add it to the sun
  document.getElementById("Sun2").appendChild(circle);
  // Remember its animation settings in `ball`
  ball[spec.element.id] = spec.animation;
}

function addObject() {
  // Create a spec to use with makeBall from the fields
  var spec = {
    element: {
      id: document.getElementById("new-id").value,
      class: document.getElementById("new-class").value,
      r: parseFloat(document.getElementById("new-r").value)
    },
    animation: {
      speed: parseFloat(document.getElementById("new-speed").value),
      spin: parseFloat(document.getElementById("new-spin").value),
      side: parseFloat(document.getElementById("new-side").value)
    }
  };
  // Some minimal validation
  if (!spec.element.id || !spec.element.r || !spec.animation.speed || !spec.animation.spin || isNaN(spec.animation.side)) {
    alert("Need all values to add a ball");
  } else if (ball[spec.element.id]) {
    alert("There is already a ball '" + spec.element.id + "'");
  } else {
    // Do it!
    makeBall(spec);
  }
}

function rotation(coorX, coorY, object) {
  object.side += (1.0 / object.speed);
  var ang = object.side * 2.0 * Math.PI / 180.0;
  var r = object.spin;

  return {
    x: Math.cos(ang) * r - Math.sin(ang) * r + coorX,
    y: Math.sin(ang) * r + Math.cos(ang) * r + coorY
  };
}

function rotationball(circle) {
  var x, y, x_black, y_black, e, newpos, black;

  // We always rotate around black
  black = document.getElementById("black");
  
  // Get this circle and update its position
  e = document.getElementById(circle);
  x_black = parseFloat(black.getAttribute("cx"));
  y_black = parseFloat(black.getAttribute("cy"));
  newpos = rotation(x_black, y_black, ball[circle]);

  e.setAttribute("cx", newpos.x);
  e.setAttribute("cy", newpos.y);
}

function animate() {
  Object.keys(ball).forEach(function(id) {
    rotationball(id);
  });
}

var animateInterval = setInterval(animate, 1000 / 60);
```

```css
.st0 {
  fill: black;
}
.st1 {
  fill: blue;
}
.st2 {
  fill: red;
}
.st3 {
  fill: yellow;
}
.st4 {
  fill: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>Add ball:
  <label>
    ID: <input type="text" id="new-id" value="newball">
  </label>
  <label>
    R: <input type="text" id="new-r" value="10">
  </label>
  <label>
    Speed: <input type="text" id="new-speed" value="1.2">
  </label>
  <label>
    Spin: <input type="text" id="new-spin" value="80">
  </label>
  <label>
    Side: <input type="text" id="new-side" value="0.0">
  </label>
  <label>
    Class: <input type="text" id="new-class" value="st4">
  </label>
  <button type="button" onclick="addObject()">
    Make Ball
  </button>
</div>

<div class="spinning">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="solly" viewBox="0 0 1000 600">
    <g id="Sun2">
      <circle id="black" class="st0" cx="500" cy="300.8" r="10" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

---

Side note: You might look at using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) rather than `setInterval`.

Side note 2: As far as I can tell, what you've called `spin` is actually the distance from the center (e.g., the radius of the circle each ball will describe around the black ball).

Comment: Hi, thank you for trying to help out. But I see that the snippet doesn't work as I would've wanted it to. It doesn't actually add in a new planet when I click the button, or that happens outside the screen size. Also, it makes rotation go a lot faster while I want it to stay the same. What would need to be changed?

Comment: @Zhyohzhy: As I said in the answer, I showed you how to create an element dynamically, but left it to you to hook up the button to do that with dynamic values. Just respond to a click on the button by calling `makeBall` with new values. Re animation speed: It's just using the same settings your original code did.

Comment: Somehow I can't implement your code into mine without some issue. I'm still learning the ropes of programming in general, would you mind if you showed your code with mine?

Comment: @Zhyohzhy: I don't know what you mean by "your code with mine" -- that's what the above was, your code modified a bit by me with explanation. I've hooked up the button for you above. Hopefully you can take it from here.

Comment: Thank you, I can definitely continue on with what you've helped me out with. This looks pretty much exactly the way how I had pictured it.

Comment: I don't mean by how the end result of the program will come to look, of course.

Comment: There is one last.. hiccup that I'm currently not getting past. I was too quick to think it's resolved, but I don't know where or how, but I can't implement the code snippets into my code. It'll only work for me on this page, in the code snippet. Not if copy/paste the code onto a site like jsfiddle/jsbin. I've read your answer a few times, and I have simply no idea where the problem lies. Could you post the answer on an alternative site ie jsfiddle?

Comment: @Zhyohzhy: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/zxfqLsc9/) is literally just a copy and paste of each section of the above (HTML, CSS, JS) into jsFiddle, and then fixing jsFiddle's stupid default of wrapping everything in a `window.onload = function() { ... };` handler. Works just fine.